# Save base64 JPG to disk in R - Shiny

Tags: r, image, shiny, jpeg

I have the following data frame which can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-PuDZ6SYpScMW5CdXhvLVpJQkk).  The column `image_path` has jpg files in base64 format.  I want to extract the image and store it in a local folder.  I tried using the code given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36708191/convert-base64-to-png-jpeg-file-in-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761336/how-to-display-images-retrieved-from-mysql-in-r-shiny/39763698#39763698).

While the second one perfectly opens the image in the browser, I couldn't figure out how to save the file locally.  I tried the following code:

```
library(shiny)
for (i in 1:length(df)){
file <- paste(df$id[i])
png(paste0(~images/file, '.png'))
tags$img(src = df$image_path[i])
dev.off()
}
```

The following just runs but doesn't create any image files and no errors are shown.  When I tried running `tags$img(src = df$image_path[1])` to see if it generates the image, it doesn't.  I understand tags$img is a function within shiny and works when I pass it inside ui (as suggested by @daatali), but not sure how do I save the files locally.

What I want is to run a for loop from inside a server environment of shiny and save the images locally as jpg using id numbers as filename, which can be rendered with various other details captured in the survey.

I have never worked with images and please bear with me if this is completely novice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates your images from the base64 strings and saves the files **to your current working directory, subfolder "/images/"**. [This article describes pretty well how to save files locally in Shiny.](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html#local)

```
library(shiny)
library(base64enc)
filepath <- "images/"
dir.create(file.path(filepath), showWarnings = FALSE)
df <- read.csv("imagefiletest.csv", header=T, stringsAsFactors = F)
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(df[i,"image_path"] == "NULL"){
    next
  }
  testObj <- strsplit(df[i,"image_path"],",")[[1]][2]
  inconn <- testObj
  outconn <- file(paste0(filepath,"image_id",df[i,"id"],".png"),"wb")
  base64decode(what=inconn, output=outconn)
  close(outconn)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton....Truly appreciate....Have been breaking my head over the last two days...this really helps....thank you.